# How do I handle an "incompatible" project in an opensource C# solution (digiCamControl)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I am new to C# and have been trying to build digiCamControl on Visual Express 2013. The project CameraControl.Service is displayed as "incompatible" when building the solution. All other modules get added to the project without any problem.

1) Can you suggest why I could be facing this problem?

2) Can you suggest a fix for the problem?

Here is a link to the particular project inside digiCamControl, which is causing the "incompatiblity" error -   https://github.com/dukus/digiCamControl/blob/master/CameraControl.Service/CameraControl.Service.csproj

3) Looking into this file, its a visual studio 2005 project (though opening it on some versions of Visual Express C# 2010, says that "you need a newer version" ?

< ProductVersion > 8.0.50727 < /ProductVersion >

(the id here is of visual studio 2005)

4) Do I need to migrate the project into 2013?

I want to use devenv.exe /upgrate to migrate the project - but it is not available on my Visual Studio C# 2013 (Community download) OR I cant find it.

I am downloading Ultimate Version to see if its available there.

---

Some other things, this is a WCF solution (if that helps).

Thanks in advance. ~ Naval

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open the project and build it successfully with the Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

Note: building successfully required some config changes, but those are more specific to the particular project (such as enabling unsafe operations).